# max. queries running parallel in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hangfire

We have a C# app using Hangfire to run report on SQL Server. 
Hangfire simply runs tasks parallel. Currently it is set up to run 20 reports parallel, and that's what I see on the dashboard, 20 reports are running, and some are waiting.

but if I open SQL Server, I see that only 2 report-related queries are actually running. And I usually see 1 or 2 report queries in "suspended" or "runnable" status.

What is the reason of this? Is it because somehow SQL Server thinks that more parallelism wouldn't help? Or is it because of configuration? I couldn't really find anything relevant, articles are usually talk about "Max. degree of parallelism", but that is the level of parallelism within the query. It is set to 0.

thanks

Comment: Maybe your SQL Server has run out of resources. I like to use `sp_WhoIsActive` to observe what's going on

Comment: Are your queries referencing any of the same objects as well? Might be that one of those reports is causing a table lock, and thus the other report(s) can't run.

Comment: What other "parallelism" would you think parallel refers to, if not the threading at the CPU level? SQL Server engine will perform other tasks if it is waiting on resources (I/O, memory, etc.) so perhaps you may get more information checking the wait stats. There may be no problem at all.

Comment: Could you clarify the value of option "Maximum Number of Concurrent connections" (Db>Properties> Connections)? It should be equal 0 or more than 20 in your case. Also, you think correctly about "Max. degree of parallelism". It's within the query.

Comment: Consult `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` to see if there are any queries waiting on the SQL end. Using this view effectively is a bit of work; try [this one](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/updated-sys-dm_os_waiting_tasks-script-2/) for starters. SQL Server will run all queries you fire at it in parallel, but if those queries themselves need a lot of resources, most of them won't be able to make progress. You may be able to reduce their resource needs (for example, by reducing the `MAXDOP` of each query), but that depends on what kind of waits you get.